# Are user accounts on data.stackexchange.com and Stack Exchange two different entities?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid

I tried to search for similar questions, as I always do, but was not able to find one.

I just created a new [account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/7032/kishor-nanda) on Data.Stack Exchange with my existing Google OpenID and it seems to be not associated with my regular Stack Exchange account.

Is this by design? and if so, why?

Comment: What do you mean by **`not associated`**?

Comment: When I created the Data explorer account, the user id was `jon.doe7033`. So I edited the profile to look like my regular SE profiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange Data Explorer started off as a side project by [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) before he started working for Stack Exchange Inc. Post that, it's received some changes but the login & auth has remained a separate part and isn't integrated into GlobalAuth that powers Stack Exchange.

So yes, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: That is nice to know.

Comment: Is it possible to link the two accounts in any way?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Fwiw, as far as I know it's similar to the reasons that [Area 51 logins aren't integrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292827/why-is-area-51-excluded-from-universal-login) -- different codebase, no access to global login sessions = a ton of work to integrate.