# Data.stackexchange wrong username

Tags: bug, data-explorer, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer)
>   [Wrong user when logging into Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer)
>   [Are user accounts on Data.StackExchange and StackExchange two different entities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115131/are-user-accounts-on-data-stackexchange-and-stackexchange-two-different-entities)

I just created an account on data.stackexchange (exactly the same way I did on other stackexchange sites) using my gmail account, although it found my account ok, my username didn't come through - it created a new username Jon.doeXXXX.

Is this a bug or does data.stackexchange not use my main account (it does not show up under my accounts list)?

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen question 115131.