# Why do I see multiple Stack Exchange accounts on the My Logins page?

Tags: support, user-accounts

However I've changed my logins a few times, I would expect to have only one Stack Exchange account. I dug my emails and got the following history.

- Registered with StackOverflow by Facebook login (2014).
- Set a password by 'Account Recovery' and started to use my e-mail/password (2017).
- Registered with SE Area 51 using the same e-mail (2017).
- Removed my Facebook account from my logins (2020).

[image: se accounts]

My account was always stick to the same e-mail address. Why do I see multiple accounts, is Area 51 considered a different account?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292827/why-is-area-51-excluded-from-universal-login Not quite a duplicate but it does show Area 51 is a separate log in.

Comment: @MarkKirby This was my first guess as well. The related question doesn't confirm 100%, but 99%. Still more than enough.

Comment: I noticed something similar after visiting https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current. See https://i.imgur.com/ic2OIwJ.png. The 'used X mins ago' values are the same, so that suggests the credentials are one & the same thing.