# Difference between changing password with Email and with Stack Exchange

Tags: support, user-accounts, password

I want to change my Stack Overflow (and as far as I know that will change it for all other Stack Exchange sites) profile. First, I really have to mention, that UI is very bad - I needed to google "how to change Stack Overflow password".

Why are there two entries (with my email and with "Stack Exchange" label) and what makes them different?

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate (with no answer): [Why do I see multiple Stack Exchange accounts on the My Logins page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342914/348196)

Comment: For what it's worth, both "buttons" will direct you to the exact same page, so there's no difference. It _is_ really confusing though; I agree.

Comment: I suspect one of them might have to do with the old Stack Exchange OpenID system. Essentially, in the past, the core of the login system was based around OpenID, and simple email/password authentication was handled around a special OpenID provider (Stack Exchange OpenID) that SE had set up. However, it was later integrated into the site directly.

Comment: @JitendraSingh https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins//{user-id} you just go to `Settings -> Your logins`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine maybe we can turn this into a feature request then? yeah, both head to the same URL and I have a feeling, that it's absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @JitendraSingh that's because you're registered here with your Google account and StackExchange won't (and can't) change your Google password.. and still - it's two, can't you see that? just one doesn't have a "Change password" button.